# Filtrar datos de una coleccion por fecha

Tags: mongodb

Necesito filtrar las ocurrencias de la última hora de la siguiente consulta de mongodb;

```
db.OPERATIONS.find({"Description":"Not playable."}).count()
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asumiendo que no tienes el campo **`fecha`** en la Coleccion , te comento que con el [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/index.html) puedes tener la fecha que se registro la solicitud puedes verlo de la siguiente forma:

```
ObjectId.getTimestamp()
```

Una vez aclarado esto.. lo siguiente es buscar los registro de la ultima hora(***una hora de diferencia con respecto la actual***) ; debes calcular la ultima hora y compararlo con el **`timestamp`** del **ObjectId()**, la diferencia es que no lo podemos hacer directamente, debemos usar la funcion **$where** para poder calcular la fecha

Puedes hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
db.OPERATIONS.find({ 
    $where: 
    function() { 
        var ultimaHora = new Date();
        ultimaHora.setHours(ultimaHora.getHours() - 1);
        return this.Description ==  "Not playable" &&   this._id.getTimestamp() >= ultimaHora 
        } 
    }).count()
```

Comment: Funciona! Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas y vuestro tiempo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Mira si entendí bien quieres sacar los docs de Descripción: not playable de la ultima hora
puedes usar los operadores  *$and, $eq y $gte*.

- el $and especificara que ambos campos deben ser validos el
- $eq que debe ser igual el campo descripción a "Not Playable"
- y el $gte que la  fecha sea mayor a la fecha ingresada

$gte es >=  puedes usar tambien $gt que es >

```
db.operations.find(
  {$and: [ 
     { "Description": { $eq:"Not playable"  } }, 
     { fecha: { $gte: "La fecha" } } 
  ] } 
)
```

quizá el query no este ordenado exactamente por que no se como manejes la fecha pero esos operadores deberían ayudarte si o si

Comment: que pasa si no tiene fecha?

Comment: checa esta funcion  "ObjectId("ID_OBJETO").getTimestamp()"

Comment: como object id es la fecha en formato timestamp con ordenarlos de mayor a menor y mostrar los ultimos 30 seran las incidencias que el necesita